# getting error : Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I want to check if database is connected or not in my express js api, but it gives me error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`, can anyone please help me why i am getting this error, here i have added my full code, can anyone please look in that and help me to resolve this issue,

```
dbconnection.db :

{
        username: process.env.DB_USERNAME || '****',
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '',
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE || '*****',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
        dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT || 'mysql',
        logging: false,  
}

API : 
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconnection.db);
        connection.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                return res.send(err.message).end();
            }
        });
        res.statusCode = 200;
        return res.send('OK').end(); 
    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        return res.send(error).end();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should send success response inside the callback as follows:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconnection.db);
        connection.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                return res.send(err.message).end();
            } else {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                return res.send('OK').end(); 
        });

    } catch (error) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        return res.send(error).end();
    }
});
```